# How to let Android Studio know that there is a wrong argument value?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, annotations

I find Android Studio a very good IDE. It seems like that it will tell you when you enter a wrong argument for a method. For instance:

```
view.setVisibility(1);
```

Android Studio says that I can only use `View.GONE`, `View.INVISIBLE` and `View.VISIBLE` for that argument. When I go into the definition of the `setVisibility` method, I see that there is an annotation on the parameter, called "`@Visibility`". So I guess Android Studio uses annotations to check whether the argument is valid. But how do I create my own annotations that can be checked by Android Studio?

For example, I have this method:

```
public void moveHorizontally (int direction) {
    //code
}
```

I want the direction argument to be either `LEFT` or `RIGHT` which are constants defined in this class.

How can I create such an annotation so that Android Studio can detect invalid arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the annotation `@IntDef` for exactly this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html

However, personally, I think it's better to just use an enum.

```
public enum Direction { LEFT, RIGHT }
```

Comment: Did you use `@IntDef` or an `enum`?

Comment: I used `@IntDef` because I don't want an enum.

Comment: Fair enough. Glad I could help.